# Adding items to an array that is a member variable in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, class

My assignment is to add animals that I have created to an enclosure.  Animal is an abstract class used to create 4 animals one of which is "croc".  Unfortunately I receive an error message when I try to add items to an enclosure.

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   //animals and enclosures created sucessfully here.

   firstEnclosure.addAnimal(croc);

}
```

```
public class Enclosure {
    private Animal[] animals;

    public void setAnimal(Animal[] animal){
        this.animals = animal;
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
       setAnimal(animal);

}
```

The error message reads:

> error: incompatible types: Animal cannot be converted to Animal[]
> setAnimal(animal);

Comment: You are trying to set an animal object using an array in setAnimal

Comment: Welcome!
Your question seems to be programming-language-specific (it's not JavaScript, for example).
Please add the appropriate programming-language tag (by editing your questions, same place where "arrays" and "class" are).
Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Where is your Animal class? Also, you're missing a closing brace in your Main class.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the issue:

```````
public class Enclosure {
    private Animal[] animals;

    public void setAnimal(Animal[] animal){
        this.animals = animal;
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
       setAnimal(animal); // <--**Setting Animal object to the Animal array Object**
}
``````
```````